# npm wildcards break stylus compilation in cygwin

Tags: node.js, npm, cygwin, stylus, npm-run

I have the following `package.json`

`{
  "name": "express-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "stylus source/stylesheets/* -o static/css/",
    "watch-css": "stylus source/stylesheets/index.styl -o static/css -w",
    "clean": "rm -rf static\\css && mkdir static\\css",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build-css",
    "watch": "npm run clean && npm run watch-css & nodemon server -e js,jade",
    "start": "node server"
 },
  "dependencies": {
    # bleh
  }
}`

And when I run `npm run build` in cygwin, I get the following errors:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\sherlock\source\stylesheets\*'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build-css"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! express-example@0.0.0 build-css: `stylus source/stylesheets/* -o static/css/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

However, if I run the command myself (again in cygwin), it works fine:

```
$ stylus source/stylesheets/*.styl -o static/css/
  compiled static\css\index.css
```

Is there something I can do to get around this?

Comment: Is the  `.styl` suffix intentionally missing from your command in the `build-css` npm script?... the command you're running via the CLI appears different to the one in npm script.

Comment: It fails either way, with or without the `.styl`